# Is there an Instagram streaming API like Twitter stream API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm creating an application to collect data from Instagram. I'm looking for a streaming API like Twitter stream API so that I can collect data at real-time automatically without having to send requests.

Is there an API like that for Instagram?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not Really

The closest thing seems to be a server callback based API as explained here: http://blog.instagram.com/post/8756150468/a-real-time-api-for-next-generation-apps

documentation here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/

Instagram would post HTTP requests to your server after you subscribe, and you could create a real time experience that way, but they do not have long polling HTTP connections like the twitter streaming API

Also, unfortunately, the future of the realtime API doesn't look promising with the deprecation of some of their realtime endpoints mentioned in the [API changelog](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/)

> Nov 17, 2015
>
> ...
>
> - Deprecation of Realtime subscriptions for tags, locations and geographies

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is an instagram public API. @lenhhoxung you can follow this link          `https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/` to get the more details about instagram API.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see an API like streaming API from Twitter.

Comment: There is no streaming API like Twitter, you can however get API for a hashtag or specific location